# Refactoring my app next steps?

Tags: reactjs

I made a sample project using React and Redux and the NASA Mars rover API that basically is an input field where you put the date in YYYY-MM-DD format and hit enter and it returns a row of data showing the date you put in, the rover name, and a picture the rover took on that day. Right now I have coded my React App to where the rover it gets this from is the rover called 'opportunity'.

I am wanting this app to have the ability to select a drop down with the options of choosing 'opportunity', 'curiosity', or 'spirit', but am unsure how to do this.

I am not sure how to proceed. I had tried making a new class based component for the drop down menu called rover_select and had it's own state in there but was never able to get that working and am not sure if my approach is correct.

I have a search bar component called query_bar which will have a child component of rover_select which is where the code for the drop-down menu is.

Here is query_bar.js

```js
class QueryBar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { searchdate: '' };

        this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
        this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    onInputChange(event) {

        this.setState({ searchdate: event.target.value });
    }

    onFormSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        //we need to fetch rover data

        console.log("my test",this.state.searchdate)


        this.props.fetchRoverData(this.state.searchdate);
        this.setState({ searchdate: '' });
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} className="input-group">

                    <input placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" className="form-control" value={this.state.searchdate}  onChange={this.onInputChange} />

                    <span className="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary">Submit</button>
                    </span>
                    <SelectRover />

            </form>
        );
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({ fetchRoverData }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(QueryBar);
```

then rover_select.js

```js
class SelectRover extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { rovervalue: 'opportunity' };

        this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
    }

    onInputChange(event) {

        this.setState({ rovervalue: event.target.value });

        this.props.fetchRoverName(this.state.rovervalue);

        console.log('rover selected',this.state.rovervalue);
    }

    render() {
        return (

                <label>
                    Select A Rover:                 
                        <select value={this.state.rovervalue} onChange={this.onInputChange} className="form-control" name="Rovers">
                            <option value="curiosity">Curiosity</option>
                            <option value="opportunity">Opportunity</option>
                            <option value="spirit">Spirit</option>
                        </select>
                </label>
        );
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({ fetchRoverName }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SelectRover);
```

Basically I heavily modified code from a React Course from Stephen Grider, part of that code is also an action creator js file called index.js that uses axios and promises, in that component there is a function called fetchRoverData(date) which gets the date entered from the search bar and puts that date the user enters and adds it to the url, I am basically trying to do the same but with the vale of the drop down the user selects and have that value be added to the url that gets made here in index.js inside my actions folder.

index.js (inside my actions folder)

```js
const API_KEY= 'D5XmTzyRFPHDzKv3yBRMWwwtfYd7Ui986j8vC2KM';

const ROVER_NAME='opportunity';

const FIRST_PART_ROOT_URL = `https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/${ROVER_NAME}/photos?earth_date=`;

const SECOND_PART_ROOT_URL = `&api_key=${API_KEY}`;

export const FETCH_ROVER_DATA = 'FETCH_ROVER_DATA';

export function fetchRoverName(name) {
        return {
        type: ROVER_NAME,
    };

}

export function fetchRoverData(date) {

    const url = `${FIRST_PART_ROOT_URL}${date}${SECOND_PART_ROOT_URL}`;

    const request = axios.get(url);

    console.log('Request:', request);

    return {
        type: FETCH_ROVER_DATA,
        payload: request
    };
}
```

All my source code for this project is [here](https://github.com/aalfr494/NASA-rover-app) (this is the 1.0 version without the drop down, it works with just one rover name hard coded in it). Can someone point me in the right direction on how I should proceed? Should the select drop down even be a separate component?

Comment: You'll start to get answers to your question if you edit it down to a small example.  Although the mars rover context is interesting, it distracts from what you're actually trying to ask help on and should probably be removed.  Please read this article then edit this question down to maybe 10-20% of where it is now: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ok, thank you, first time using stack overflow to post, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just keep it one component and put that `<select>` tag that you are referring to in the `query_bar` component.

Then allow the user to enter the date and select the rover name, 
update those new values in your components state variables i.e. using `this.setState({ nameOfStateVariable: newValue});`

then on the users submit call the one function (`fetchRoverData()` ) from the actions. Send the date and the rover_name when you call the function i.e. `fetchRoverData(date, rover_name)`  and substitute them both into your url in the correct spot as you were doing before in your index.js(in actions folder)

Hope this helps

Comment: Wow! Hey, this really helped me a ton!! I followed your advice, along with setting another state property (did not know you can have two states) like so this.state = { searchdate: '', rovername: 'opportunity' };

After doing that and following your advice it now works! Thank you SO MUCH! You are amazing!